# Replace value within the string with specified keyword in PHP

Tags: php, string, replace

I have this string

`../../some/folder/image.png`

and it's possible that the string will be

`../../../../../../some/folder/image.png`

and I want to **remove all** `../` and **add** `/root/folder/` in front of `some/folder/image.png`.
How do I do this?

**edit**

And sometime that string is placed in the middle. I mean it might be like this:

`hallo hallo ../../../some/folder/image.png`.

Comment: I can see where this is going but there's no way you can reach a secure environment like that if you start including different character sets, etc. I suggest instead of passing that in the URL, you should pass only command names, for example "ParentFolder" and compute the target path on the server side only.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following :

```
$path = "hello lol ../../some/folder/image.png";
$path = preg_replace("#.*\.\./#", "", $path);
$path = "/root/folder/" . $path;
```

Comment: The problem is sometime that string is placed in the middle. I mean it might be like this: `hallo hallo ../../../some/folder/image.png`. Your solution will make it to be like this: `/root/folder/hallo hallo some/folder/image.png`

Comment: Edited my answer to match what you want.

Comment: and sometimes it removes `../../` but the `/root/folder/` is added before the string like this `/root/folder/hello lol some/folder/image.png`. What I want is  `hello lol /root/folder/some/folder/image.png`.

Comment: I re-posted my solution, it should work either way, regardless of the string before

Answer (score 0):

Depends where you want to use it, but you would do something like this

```
$path = "../../../../../some/folder/image.png";
$searchFor = substr($path, 0, strpos( $path, "some"));

$path = str_replace($searchFor, "/root/folder/", $path);
```

I know the preg_replace() is better, but I wanted to share a different answer

Comment: It won't work, it will replace `../` with `/root/folder/`multiple times if the `../` string is present multiple times.

Comment: @Timur but isn't it going to replace each individual `../` with `/root/folder/`, is it? So in another word, if I have this `../../../some/folder/image.png` it will generate three `/root/folder/` s and the string will be `/root/folder//root/folder//root/folder/root/folder/some/folder/image.png`?